# How to prevent exception when code cannot be decrypted?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I have a public web hook that a service is calling in order to send my website notifications. In this web hook, I am expecting an encrypted token. When I get the token, I decrypt it using a predefined key and check that the token is what I was expecting. This works fine.

When an unencrypted or bad token is passed into the function, the decryption will of course fail. This is OK, **but I don't want an exception to be generated** when this happens. If some hacker creates 1,000,000 bad requests against my web hook in a second and each request takes 1 second to process a huge exception, it will crash my server.

Here is my decryption code so far:

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string key)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = key;
        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");

        //I added this to prevent exception when trying to Convert.FromBase64String()
        if (cipherText.Length % 4 != 0)
        {
            //cipherText must be a length that is a multiple of 4, otherwise it will fail
            return null;
        }

        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();  //currently giving exception HERE
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

It is giving me an exception at cs.Close() `The input data is not a complete block` when I intentionally pass in a non-encrypted string. I am not sure what exactly is being checked here, so I don't know how to prevent it.

**How can I refactor this code so that if a string cannot be decrypted it won't throw me an exception?**

Comment: I think you need to make sure that your `cipherBytes` length is divisible by the `encryptor.BlockSize`. This might be annoying if you're actually trying to handle a stream of data. But if you're just taking a string, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If you let a hacker create 1,000,000 bad requests and still do nothing to stop him, then you have already done something terribly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `catch` the exception and do with it what you want. (log, reroute, ignore, etc).  Try/catch documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: I am aware of try/catch, but I thought if I "catch" the exception then it doesn't solve my issue of "If some hacker creates 1,000,000 bad requests against my web hook in a second and each request takes 1 second to process a huge exception, it will crash my server." ??

Comment: @AlbatrossCafe This is the correct way to handle it. Of course you can subvert the crypto API and handle things yourself so it doesn't throw an exception, but then you are into even more dangerous territory: (re)implementing cryptography. This is much worse. Just handle the exception like you should, and implement some rate limiting to prevent the scenario you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

When you decrypt a ciphertext with a non-authenticated mode like CBC, an padding error can detect a wrong key or wrong final block with a probability of roughly 255 times of 256 times. This happens when the final block is corrupted and no valid padding can be found. [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7) is used by default and it has a special structure that can be validated.

You can request the decryptor not to attempt unpadding in any way with:

```
encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

but then you need to unpad yourself (padding bytes can be only in the range of 1 to 16 for AES):

```
var ctBytes = ms.ToArray();
var last = ctBytes[ctBytes.Length-1];
if (last < 17 && last > 0) {
    cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ctBytes.Take(ctBytes.Length - last));
} else {
    ciphertext = null;
}
```